# Katalon Studio missing report after upgrade from 5 to 6

Tags: testing, katalon-studio

How to save a report into a special directory from cmd?

I have this cmd arguments:

```
-summaryReport -reportFolder="C:\testagent\test_repo"
```

Basic report plugin installed. Selected HTML report. But after execution I have only these 3 files: `execution.properties`, `execution.uuid`, `execution0.log` in `C:\testagent\test_repo`.

In the Katalon 5 I had HTML reports after execution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append your Plugin Store API key to the command. Please refer to [this post](https://forum.katalon.com/t/using-basic-report-plugin-as-of-katalon-6-1-5/25326?u=devalex88).

Comment: done but without any result.only 3 files in the directory. execution.properties execution.uuid execution0.log from gui report is generated